# How do I convert 09/24/2015 into 20150924?

Tags: java

How can one convert the input date formatted as `mm/dd/yyyy` into an integer formatted as `yyyymmdd`.

I tried:

```
 SimpleDateFormat ft = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
 String input = "09/25/2015"; 
 String t;
 t = ft.format(input);
```

and

```
SimpleDateFormat ft = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
   String input = "09/25/2015";
   String t;
   try{
     t = ft.parse(input);
   }catch (ParseException e){      
   }
}
```

Neither of these worked; The first one gave me a runtime error.

Comment: So your input is a string?

Comment: [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) is your friend.

Comment: Please show your effort. Did you make any research or coding attempt whatsoever?

Comment: Not really sure how to do this. We use the M3 converter tool COMDAT to convert dates, but in this case it doesn't work. I tried this:   SimpleDateFormat ft = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
String input = "09/25/2015";
String t;
t = ft.format(input); Probably didn't have any chance of working, so I came to the experts.

Comment: @KinnethHerring I would advise you to place what you just commented into your question and vote for reopen. As I can see, you actually did put in some effort.

Comment: OK - I added my code snippets to the question. How do I vote for re-open?

Comment: @KinnethHerring Under your question, there is edit | reopen | delete | flag. Just click on reopen. Alternatively you can flag your own question for Moderator's attention to request them to open this question.

Comment: `new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd").format(new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy").parse("09/24/2015"))`, but it's lenient by default, so it'll process bad dates. You have to call `setLenient(false)` on the MDY formatter before calling `parse` to reject bad dates.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming the input date is in type of a String:

```
String strDate = "09/24/2015";
String[] tok = strDate.split("/");
System.out.println(tok[2] + tok[0] + tok[1]);
```

You can split them into tokens.

Comment: It is a string, but I was hoping that there was a way to do this that also allowed for some date validation.

Comment: Shorter version using regex: `"09/24/2015".replaceFirst("^(\\d{2})/(\\d{2})/(\\d{4})$", "$3$1$2")`

Comment: @KinnethHerring If it is a String, there are many ways to do it including the above solution which is also valid. You can do your own validation, especially after you already tokenized them. You can do it like `month= Integer.parseInt(tok[1])` then check `if(month > 0 && < 13)`.

Comment: I have already taken the suggested code and am validating it through the software available to me in M3. Thanks for everyone's help. The light bulb went off when I saw the token code. I already had the dates split out and should have known how to get it.

Comment: @KinnethHerring Glad it helps. You can consider accepting my solution by clicking the hollow tick beside my answer. You also get a 2 rep in return.

Comment: Java already has a built-in implementation of a strict (non-lenient) validating date parser, so why reinvent the wheel?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in two ways: String manipulation, or date parsing and reformatting.

```
// String substitution using regular expression
System.out.println("09/24/2015".replaceFirst("^(\\d{2})/(\\d{2})/(\\d{4})$", "$3$1$2"));

// Lenient date reformatting
System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd").format(new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy").parse("09/24/2015")));
```

String substitution will do nothing for bad formats, and will convert good formats even if date values are bad.

The date reformatting will fail (exception) for bad formats, and will "adjust" bad date values (see below), because it's lenient by default. Change to strict to also fail on bad date values:

```
// Strict date reformatting
SimpleDateFormat mdy = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
mdy.setLenient(false);
SimpleDateFormat ymd = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
System.out.println(ymd.format(mdy.parse("09/24/2015")));
```

The above three methods will all print:

```
20150924
```

To show the effect of bad date values,a dn with bad formats:

```
// Showing results with bad date
System.out.println("09/34/2015".replaceFirst("^(\\d{2})/(\\d{2})/(\\d{4})$", "$3$1$2"));
System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd").format(new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy").parse("09/34/2015")));
try { ymd.format(mdy.parse("09/34/2015")); } catch (Exception e) { System.out.println(e); }

// Showing results with bad formats
System.out.println("Hello".replaceFirst("^(\\d{2})/(\\d{2})/(\\d{4})$", "$3$1$2"));
try { new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy").parse("Hello"); } catch (Exception e) { System.out.println(e); }
try { ymd.format(mdy.parse("Hello")); } catch (Exception e) { System.out.println(e); }
```

*Output*

```
20150934
20151004
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "09/34/2015"

Hello
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Hello"
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Hello"
```